# Drupal 7 image field size and crop on upload

Tags: drupal, image-processing, drupal-7

I created a module that pulls images into a slider using the nivo jquery plugin, but when I upload the image, and select the image style that formats the size as I want, it doesn't actually change the image size. Apparently the image resizes on page load because looking at the node for that content type the image is the right size. However, when the nivo plugin pulls the image uisng ajax it comes in the wrong size. Is there some way I can create an image style will change the image into different size and crop upon upload, so it is that size at it's physical path?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php - and specifically at the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-resizeimage.php method, which lets you resize an image.

Here is a quick example on using imagick:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage('myimage.png');    
$img->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$img->writeImage('myNewImage.png');
$img->clear();
$img->destroy();
```

Hopefully this'll help you,

Comment: Not into Core but there is an imagemagick module: http://drupal.org/project/imagemagick. However, if you're only needing the resize image functionality it might be better to just install the imagemagick PHP package.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use Manual Crop Module. Successful Followed by this instruction: 
http://drupalcode.org/project/manualcrop.git/blob/HEAD:/README.txt

This module download [here](https://drupal.org/project/manualcrop)

Hope this help!